# Who created the design of the Ubuntu logo?

Tags: canonical, logo

Who is the designer of the Ubuntu logo?

Comment: which logo are you talking about? Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: @Zanna I believe is referencing [this](https://design.ubuntu.com/wp-content/uploads/ubuntu-logo32.png)

Comment: [This](https://design.ubuntu.com/brand/ubuntu-logo) page has some information about the logo, but not who designed it. My guess is it was one of the founders.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically Mark Shuttleworth. These where some of the early versions though (that led up to the currect one):

[image]

[image]

In 2008 [Canonical design team](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Brand), Ubuntu art team and people from all the big official versions did an overhaul of the design:

> In 2009, a small team lead by Mark Shuttleworth, conducted a review of our key brand values and identity. Based on that work, a set of visual treatments were produced, and shared with key members of the Ubuntu Art community, spanning the core distributions, derivatives, and aligned efforts like the Forums. Representatives from Ubuntu, Kubuntu, Edubuntu, Xubuntu, Mythbuntu, SpreadUbuntu and more came to London and worked with the Canonical design team to refine the designs and work together. The results of that work are presented here.

We also have [Ubuntu designers](https://design.canonical.com/2016/10/ubuntu-core/). They made the Ubuntu Core logos.

The logo is called "circle of friends".

[image]

The abstract version makes that a bit difficult to see but when you see where it came from (the 1st 2 pictures) it is pretty clear: it is 3 people stretching out their arms to make a circle.